# How soon can you reenter the US on a B-1/B-2 visa

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, b1-b2-visas, repeat-visits

I had visited the USA 4 times last year but only stay 5 days each time. My last visit was in December 2019 when I stayed for 3 days to do some shopping and return to my home country.

This year I want to visit a friend in February to spend my birthday for 5 to 7 days. Will this travel pattern draw attention? Or will is be OK?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's nothing inherently suspicious in that pattern.  The visits have been short and not particularly frequent.  In total you spent about 20 days in the US during the entire year; you're nowhere close to the point where it might look like you're doing visa runs or taking other steps to try to game the system.

On the contrary, because you have a history of visiting the US for less than a week at a time, an immigration officer is more likely to believe your statement of intention to visit for 5 to 7 days.  Enjoy the birthday celebration.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be asking two different things here.

> - How many trips can you make?
> - How long can you stay?

There doesn't appear to be a limit on how many trips you can make on a B2 visa.  Personally I made 27 trips into the US on my B2 visa in 2023.

However, the CBP officer will assess whether they believe you are attempting to reside in the US based on the number of times you enter, and the amount of time you remain in the US.  If they believe you are attempting to live in the US (8 months out of the year probably looks like that) then they can and will deny you entry (and worse).

The 6 months they allow you when you enter is for that entry.  If you attempt to enter again, they can give you 6 more months, they can give you less than 6 months, they can give you just a few days.  Or they can deny you entry altogether.  They can also revoke the visa if they believe you are misusing it.

It is up to the CBP officer to determine what you are up to, and whether you are attempting to live/work in the US illegally.

It is **up to you** to honestly describe your intentions when you enter.  If you want to be there for 8 months in a year, you will need to be honest about your intent, how you expect to pay for it, etc.

Comment: They can also give you more than six months, though this is normally indicated in uncommon circumstances.  The maximum period of admission is one year.